# How EXACTLY does the Scanner class interact with the fileReader in the following code?

Tags: java, filereader

```
try{

PrintWriter pW = new PrintWriter("newFile.txt");

pW.println("Hello");
pW.print("My name is Julian");
pW.println("");
pW.print("This is the third line");

pW.close();

FileReader fR = new FileReader("newFile.txt");

Scanner scan = new Scanner(fR);

System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
System.out.println(scan.nextLine());


}catch(Exception ex){
}
```

Thus far, I have understood that a fileReader object can use the "read" method to read data from a file into an array of characters.

However, in the above code, the Scanner object takes the fileReader object as an argument to its constructor. What is going on "under the hood" so to speak when the statement System.out.println(scan.nextLine()); is executed? How does the Scanner object "obtain" data from the fileReader object?

To conceptualize whats going on "under the hood" I imagine the Scanner object's buffer is similar to an array. Thus, what will happen under the hood is essentially the fileReader object's read method will be called, and the argument passed will be the Scanner objects buffer(something like fileReaderobject.read(Scannerobject.Scannerobjectbuffer) . Thus, the data from the file will be read into Scanner objects buffer, and we can use the next/nextLine methods to obtain this data. Is this a somewhat correct way of conceptualizing what is happening under the hood?

Comment: `I imagine the Scanner object's buffer is similar to an array` Pretty much yes. `Thus, what will happen under the hood is essentially the fileReader object's read method will be called` Again, yes, this is basically what happens.  I don't think there's any real mystery here, it works in the obvious way.

Comment: Sorry man, I'm just getting started with java, and what may seem obvious to you has really nagged me for a few days! Is this an accurate way of thinking about what might be happening under the hood: fileReaderobject.read(Scannerobject.Scannerobjectbuffer) ?

Comment: See my answer below.  I'm not sure what that `read()` method is supposed to be doing, it's not one that is actually used by `Reader`.

Answer (score 0):

FileReader is just a Reader, so Scanner likely uses the `read()` method to read a line.  Something like this:

```
Reader reader = ... (FileReader..);
public String nextLine() {
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuilder();
  int c;
  while( (c = reader.read() ) != -1 && c != '\n' )
    sb.append( (char)c );
  return sb.toString();
}
```